# Typescript: How can I extract the value from JSON objects inside an array with changing property names?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to typescript and would like to extract the value from JSON objects inside an array with changing property names.

My (simplified) code is as follows:

```
const gridData = [
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "man", "character_grid": [["i", "q", "\u00ed", "l", "n", "n", "m", "\u00f3"], ["f", "t", "v", "\u00f1", "b", "m", "h", "a"], ["h", "j", "\u00e9", "t", "e", "t", "o", "z"], ["x", "\u00e1", "o", "i", "e", "\u00f1", "m", "\u00e9"], ["q", "\u00e9", "i", "\u00f3", "q", "s", "b", "s"], ["c", "u", "m", "y", "v", "l", "r", "x"], ["\u00fc", "\u00ed", "\u00f3", "m", "o", "t", "e", "k"], ["a", "g", "r", "n", "n", "\u00f3", "s", "m"]], "word_locations": { "6,1,6,2,6,3,6,4,6,5,6,6": "hombre" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "woman", "character_grid": [["v", "\u00e1", "q", "t", "b", "f", "q"], ["y", "x", "i", "a", "\u00fc", "v", "a"], ["r", "d", "y", "\u00ed", "t", "n", "a"], ["f", "v", "\u00f3", "w", "l", "a", "v"], ["b", "u", "\u00fa", "j", "q", "h", "\u00e1"], ["c", "o", "m", "u", "j", "e", "r"], ["h", "o", "d", "\u00fa", "w", "d", "\u00fc"]], "word_locations": { "2,5,3,5,4,5,5,5,6,5": "mujer" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "boy", "character_grid": [["x", "c", "e", "x", "c", "i", "o"], ["e", "z", "q", "r", "h", "w", "y"], ["\u00f1", "\u00e9", "\u00f1", "w", "i", "n", "\u00e1"], ["o", "l", "a", "\u00e1", "c", "i", "n"], ["r", "v", "\u00f1", "s", "o", "\u00f1", "w"], ["k", "m", "w", "a", "\u00fc", "o", "w"], ["\u00f3", "r", "\u00fa", "b", "l", "g", "\u00fa"]], "word_locations": { "5,2,5,3,5,4,5,5": "ni\u00f1o", "4,0,4,1,4,2,4,3,4,4": "chico" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "girl", "character_grid": [["o", "s", "\u00f3", "x", "h", "\u00f1", "h"], ["\u00fc", "r", "g", "o", "l", "\u00fa", "b"], ["a", "t", "c", "h", "i", "c", "a"], ["u", "\u00fa", "r", "w", "\u00e1", "t", "\u00e9"], ["p", "n", "v", "r", "q", "m", "l"], ["f", "d", "t", "e", "a", "\u00f3", "l"], ["u", "t", "n", "i", "\u00f1", "a", "s"]], "word_locations": { "2,2,3,2,4,2,5,2,6,2": "chica", "2,6,3,6,4,6,5,6": "ni\u00f1a" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "am", "character_grid": [["d", "c", "e", "h", "p"], ["f", "e", "\u00fc", "p", "t"], ["s", "s", "\u00f3", "\u00ed", "l"], ["o", "s", "\u00ed", "\u00f1", "a"], ["y", "g", "i", "o", "n"]], "word_locations": { "0,2,0,3,0,4": "soy" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "she", "character_grid": [["z", "n", "w", "f", "m", "\u00e9"], ["d", "\u00f3", "q", "w", "n", "e"], ["z", "\u00e1", "v", "e", "\u00f3", "l"], ["r", "c", "z", "z", "m", "l"], ["\u00fc", "m", "\u00e1", "\u00fc", "n", "a"], ["e", "a", "e", "x", "\u00f1", "h"]], "word_locations": { "5,1,5,2,5,3,5,4": "ella" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "apple", "character_grid": [["\u00fa", "k", "\u00fc", "b", "\u00ed", "n", "z", "d", "o"], ["u", "\u00e1", "n", "g", "e", "y", "z", "o", "\u00f1"], ["o", "\u00e9", "\u00fa", "\u00e1", "v", "e", "x", "u", "m"], ["c", "w", "d", "z", "t", "k", "m", "l", "a"], ["u", "b", "o", "w", "\u00ed", "a", "u", "q", "n"], ["g", "s", "m", "e", "c", "n", "k", "\u00fa", "z"], ["a", "o", "v", "t", "p", "\u00fa", "\u00e9", "k", "a"], ["f", "j", "i", "j", "n", "i", "b", "\u00f3", "n"], ["s", "q", "l", "j", "j", "f", "q", "g", "a"]], "word_locations": { "8,2,8,3,8,4,8,5,8,6,8,7,8,8": "manzana" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "eat", "character_grid": [["i", "a", "c", "j", "r", "w"], ["k", "b", "n", "o", "u", "v"], ["v", "x", "z", "f", "m", "a"], ["u", "l", "o", "p", "e", "o"], ["l", "\u00fa", "\u00e9", "q", "j", "e"], ["a", "h", "\u00fa", "l", "k", "w"]], "word_locations": { "2,0,3,1,4,2,5,3": "como" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "bread", "character_grid": [["\u00fc", "\u00e1", "p", "a", "n"], ["k", "a", "k", "m", "l"], ["a", "x", "q", "e", "h"], ["p", "s", "a", "j", "\u00ed"], ["\u00e1", "q", "l", "j", "l"]], "word_locations": { "2,0,3,0,4,0": "pan" }, "target_language": "es" }
];

const gridDataInUse = gridData[0];

const selectedLetters = [{x: 6, y: 1, l: "h"}, {x: 6, y: 2, l: "o"}, {x: 6, y: 3, l: "m"}, {x: 6, y: 4, l: "b"}, {x: 6, y: 5, l: "r"}, {x: 6, y: 6, l: "e"}]

const letterCoordinates: number[] = []
selectedLetters.forEach((letter => {
    letterCoordinates.push(letter.x);
    letterCoordinates.push(letter.y);
}));
const letterCoordinatesAsString = letterCoordinates.join(',');
const selectedWord = selectedLetters.map((letter) => {
    return letter.l;
}).join('');
console.log(gridDataInUse.word_locations[letterCoordinatesAsString]);
```

My goal in this example is to extract "hombre" from the first JSON object in the array.

However, I get the following error message:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ "6,1,6,2,6,3,6,4,6,5,6,6": string; "2,5,3,5,4,5,5,5,6,5"?: undefined; "5,2,5,3,5,4,5,5"?: undefined; "4,0,4,1,4,2,4,3,4,4"?: undefined; "2,2,3,2,4,2,5,2,6,2"?: undefined; "2,6,3,6,4,6,5,6"?: undefined; ... 4 more ...; "2,0,3,0,4,0"?: undefined; } | ... 7 more ... | { ...; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ "6,1,6,2,6,3,6,4,6,5,6,6": string; "2,5,3,5,4,5,5,5,6,5"?: undefined; "5,2,5,3,5,4,5,5"?: undefined; "4,0,4,1,4,2,4,3,4,4"?: undefined; "2,2,3,2,4,2,5,2,6,2"?: undefined; "2,6,3,6,4,6,5,6"?: undefined; ... 4 more ...; "2,0,3,0,4,0"?: undefined; } | ... 7 more ... | { ...; }'.(7053)

How can I solve this error?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Provide a type to your array, TS is getting confused because of the "," in your word_location object, following will work

```html
interface gridItem {
    source_language: string,
    word: string,
    character_grid: Array<Array<string>>
    word_locations: Record<string, string>,
    target_language: string
}

const gridData:Array<gridItem> = [
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "man", "character_grid": [["i", "q", "\u00ed", "l", "n", "n", "m", "\u00f3"], ["f", "t", "v", "\u00f1", "b", "m", "h", "a"], ["h", "j", "\u00e9", "t", "e", "t", "o", "z"], ["x", "\u00e1", "o", "i", "e", "\u00f1", "m", "\u00e9"], ["q", "\u00e9", "i", "\u00f3", "q", "s", "b", "s"], ["c", "u", "m", "y", "v", "l", "r", "x"], ["\u00fc", "\u00ed", "\u00f3", "m", "o", "t", "e", "k"], ["a", "g", "r", "n", "n", "\u00f3", "s", "m"]], "word_locations": { "6,1,6,2,6,3,6,4,6,5,6,6": "hombre" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "woman", "character_grid": [["v", "\u00e1", "q", "t", "b", "f", "q"], ["y", "x", "i", "a", "\u00fc", "v", "a"], ["r", "d", "y", "\u00ed", "t", "n", "a"], ["f", "v", "\u00f3", "w", "l", "a", "v"], ["b", "u", "\u00fa", "j", "q", "h", "\u00e1"], ["c", "o", "m", "u", "j", "e", "r"], ["h", "o", "d", "\u00fa", "w", "d", "\u00fc"]], "word_locations": { "2,5,3,5,4,5,5,5,6,5": "mujer" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "boy", "character_grid": [["x", "c", "e", "x", "c", "i", "o"], ["e", "z", "q", "r", "h", "w", "y"], ["\u00f1", "\u00e9", "\u00f1", "w", "i", "n", "\u00e1"], ["o", "l", "a", "\u00e1", "c", "i", "n"], ["r", "v", "\u00f1", "s", "o", "\u00f1", "w"], ["k", "m", "w", "a", "\u00fc", "o", "w"], ["\u00f3", "r", "\u00fa", "b", "l", "g", "\u00fa"]], "word_locations": { "5,2,5,3,5,4,5,5": "ni\u00f1o", "4,0,4,1,4,2,4,3,4,4": "chico" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "girl", "character_grid": [["o", "s", "\u00f3", "x", "h", "\u00f1", "h"], ["\u00fc", "r", "g", "o", "l", "\u00fa", "b"], ["a", "t", "c", "h", "i", "c", "a"], ["u", "\u00fa", "r", "w", "\u00e1", "t", "\u00e9"], ["p", "n", "v", "r", "q", "m", "l"], ["f", "d", "t", "e", "a", "\u00f3", "l"], ["u", "t", "n", "i", "\u00f1", "a", "s"]], "word_locations": { "2,2,3,2,4,2,5,2,6,2": "chica", "2,6,3,6,4,6,5,6": "ni\u00f1a" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "am", "character_grid": [["d", "c", "e", "h", "p"], ["f", "e", "\u00fc", "p", "t"], ["s", "s", "\u00f3", "\u00ed", "l"], ["o", "s", "\u00ed", "\u00f1", "a"], ["y", "g", "i", "o", "n"]], "word_locations": { "0,2,0,3,0,4": "soy" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "she", "character_grid": [["z", "n", "w", "f", "m", "\u00e9"], ["d", "\u00f3", "q", "w", "n", "e"], ["z", "\u00e1", "v", "e", "\u00f3", "l"], ["r", "c", "z", "z", "m", "l"], ["\u00fc", "m", "\u00e1", "\u00fc", "n", "a"], ["e", "a", "e", "x", "\u00f1", "h"]], "word_locations": { "5,1,5,2,5,3,5,4": "ella" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "apple", "character_grid": [["\u00fa", "k", "\u00fc", "b", "\u00ed", "n", "z", "d", "o"], ["u", "\u00e1", "n", "g", "e", "y", "z", "o", "\u00f1"], ["o", "\u00e9", "\u00fa", "\u00e1", "v", "e", "x", "u", "m"], ["c", "w", "d", "z", "t", "k", "m", "l", "a"], ["u", "b", "o", "w", "\u00ed", "a", "u", "q", "n"], ["g", "s", "m", "e", "c", "n", "k", "\u00fa", "z"], ["a", "o", "v", "t", "p", "\u00fa", "\u00e9", "k", "a"], ["f", "j", "i", "j", "n", "i", "b", "\u00f3", "n"], ["s", "q", "l", "j", "j", "f", "q", "g", "a"]], "word_locations": { "8,2,8,3,8,4,8,5,8,6,8,7,8,8": "manzana" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "eat", "character_grid": [["i", "a", "c", "j", "r", "w"], ["k", "b", "n", "o", "u", "v"], ["v", "x", "z", "f", "m", "a"], ["u", "l", "o", "p", "e", "o"], ["l", "\u00fa", "\u00e9", "q", "j", "e"], ["a", "h", "\u00fa", "l", "k", "w"]], "word_locations": { "2,0,3,1,4,2,5,3": "como" }, "target_language": "es" },
  { "source_language": "en", "word": "bread", "character_grid": [["\u00fc", "\u00e1", "p", "a", "n"], ["k", "a", "k", "m", "l"], ["a", "x", "q", "e", "h"], ["p", "s", "a", "j", "\u00ed"], ["\u00e1", "q", "l", "j", "l"]], "word_locations": { "2,0,3,0,4,0": "pan" }, "target_language": "es" }
];

const gridDataInUse = gridData[0];

const selectedLetters = [{x: 6, y: 1, l: "h"}, {x: 6, y: 2, l: "o"}, {x: 6, y: 3, l: "m"}, {x: 6, y: 4, l: "b"}, {x: 6, y: 5, l: "r"}, {x: 6, y: 6, l: "e"}]

const letterCoordinates: number[] = []
selectedLetters.forEach((letter => {
    letterCoordinates.push(letter.x);
    letterCoordinates.push(letter.y);
}));
const letterCoordinatesAsString = letterCoordinates.join(',');
const selectedWord = selectedLetters.map((letter) => {
    return letter.l;
}).join('');
console.log(gridDataInUse.word_locations[letterCoordinatesAsString]);
```

you can check the below link that by providing type it is not compaling

[Working Code Without Error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=41&pln=4&pc=21#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOZWAEwJKQLbIDeAUMmcgM4D2ArlEgPoA2cIqNcqEAXJWBmwA0pcgHcqUTLwr9QqYeWQIAFnCiJIUBuiy8AglHUBPADwHjJmQNQA%20GyLLjJzKgjhhgVEBV4AlCAgSmJayQnzWNgrkYGpcYMys7Jw84XLEAL7ExIHeYGgYmAAi7nDc5nCmOjj4NsgAvMgA2iKEyABE1HSMLGwcXG28bRAgbYLtTpgD7Xiso%200qahrQ2gVTjY1twHNtAI7bADo0AAxHEJNjbUzbIxc30wfHRzAAzG0AumMbMNtg2wBuDxOMAAjNsAEbbPDbZTbODvT5tGEXABWgNOAE4ftsIFiLlRtgAveFNNoADzREFBeO2WwuOIuhyBVPuDMeEExHxJe1ZJ3ZNLRL223PaFHB21FnI2CG2NEh2yM-22VwuUG25MlbUZT2lPNO53aWsFFyh1Iuvzp2wA1sSNnCLqhtqrbtcBa8LqLje9OW0Ji43B4vKLeK02gA2QTAwThgBMUcEzzjABY4wBWOOhqaIqh4MFQHHIdJm2IQeI9JL9QYQUUFqIhzr0CAJXrJTPDbYTTPiGZ3NoLdQITQrLBrDYA3WUoW49oQi7fC57DUKi7ki609p2g2PGA69pj9c2tpO9r6tpLze8k-m9o9uEaue713tpWwxUamftWW6%20DbVHz6EU0ENR3Np8U9C5P3aX92npdpVQ1JF2lA48BQ3H1thPQ1pTeb1fSYVx3E8bwphDWM0wTNNkzTKjU0zPAaGRaA2hrdoYigOIm3LHFK2rQsWhFWgGw4vouOgnsO0GMEqDPXtVH7QcqhHMltmAmClIuYC1xAg9VKJP8VX-C5RHlA9DWZTU2UxL8zKM1cXXHQCESQy4X3s5T%20WdDUjzaPdzKZcVtic0ynw1a0wPGFzz21ALgoRQ03VglCxQuZV2gdL9bxwoI-QIwNiPaNNSPjQQKOK4rMxAYBTKc5MjkEZNI2TWNkwTZNE0zFRgECJjCxY4tS0SYTWx42t%20K6Rsy0GysxKCTNUGAKAUpkxYB2WBTeHWLT3UfZcDMikF-w1TDHW2NLEOfdKxQ1VCr17XbNjci5bwRCDfKeVCvJsyKJzNCkOQRAAHOyH30vSWXaK473Qqchgi16jXBg8XpuntNKCx7-Owwysrw-1CKDIh2ljWMEyawRCtjGN2uUTrUIporw2TcM0wzQYKtMuFmLaVj2ImltuO6kaOgE7oBr50T2xmwY4BNeZZKWLQ1qaDYTxUu7Achi0v2AwGfo1D0RW2r6Twhxz-PHDCtzMp6SWk077tNa8vSx5wcZyojg3aWrY1qhNarawZqAVTnuZLISxaGYa%20KFsaw4rcXncmAPlFUvt5aHROlbaXTHcM7Z7zaGXXr5DULaBeLdifZ0LQ1bOi7MnzVLi59PIe9pa9rwuTZJI6wrrgVgJvbTYdUlc9rMmFMfGbH8IDd2CbaNNIwK0ryLq1smBYAXerY0PebjiOBaj%20sRebfe2wTzM4H%20-6mBTuWVoV1Z1o2Q1UNCvbgPfIuTx7WuT3xDUL0tTfRzqlbExkLi10CpbA80DeSWT2qhYB9dwE7XAnKICldkKQOhu-Au519yAKSmdXO5tYYvWFG0EYGo7b63wZreYQM2h4NfoSA8qEnI%20RujrRBv0rQvg1pBdyQiq7tE0l-JuHkER0MoYtKCbR5H50oXbDKCdsqz3xiGAAHGTQQOiEw6OTDotMOjww6IAOx6L0bRVgBJWAcx6lzPqscRIHxrEfYW41RZn2mpIVs7hlL33kk-TOmlULAXkR9A8eCv49ici9AEGofKjyznnOU6MiHJWihcHhMNqQakWqw8cCCK4onAVdO6RSEYXDwUZSePpp641yh7No3sioNV0WRdq2Z8TB2cXvVxVZD5kDrJ4lxrZfEZzaLmCAcAVZBNWiEjaPcvpmVyahahCI8Fv3SQjCpaD2iUNUhPAGZt9xlLIYdNkZlZE-mbplF2M88Z5VaYIH2by6pvMzP9WYfSd79VPoMnixA3gAG4sg5BkPkLAxQYjYBAAAVQoCgBoVRYVwEaEcMFELAx5GRbfFamAAAyJZNAUHqE0QgpJeDhmQEYXgkZkBMEGDCHqVKaVjHpcgWMTLBj4jZdS5AtKuUJl5fcAVHK6W8GTGK6ZbQJVCs5bwNMsrVQKuFZK5l0F5VvBxbkJlpLoAAGEqBBFAO4KsvAQA0BzNARobwKX2uIPigIkBiWGqgBQAAdDACQABRRAygAAUQbb5gE0PUWoJBFBhs0Cas1IALXev%20jQCgwbY3QC9aSAAlOCmNHr42SHNZAZNqb00eq9UYXNGRs3VshXkDNUBC2YGLVWPQFAADKoRUAUsbc21t3rkRUFAEGgA5IIUddbcWUAgASt1AB1IIFKXWEpJeG6A3qZj-RDY27NkaiAOGQHmMAdAQAGvXVAL1TBwXpGzV6odI7R2TvBZCqgt8r1UFQEGtFJR4VIogF63CTzAyND7aaotiaS3tq7dYN4uagA)

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely certain that every `letterCoordinatesAsString` you construct will have a matching property in the object you're looking at, a simple enough fix would be to tell TS that the `word_locations` object is a `Record<string, string>`, allowing you to look up the object with your `letterCoordinatesAsString` string:

```
const gridData: Array<{
    source_language: string;
    word: string;
    // ...
    word_locations: Record<string, string>;
}> = [
  { "source_language": "en", ...
```

TypeScript generally doesn't play as nicely with dynamic property names as would be ideal. Another option is to resort to a type assertion after an `in` check, that tests whether the property exists on the object, telling the *programmer* that it's safe to access, but without giving TypeScript more information to infer from.

```
const { word_locations } = gridDataInUse;
if (letterCoordinatesAsString in word_locations) {
    console.log((word_locations as Record<string, string | undefined>)[letterCoordinatesAsString]);
}
```

Typing the data `as const` could help, turning the `word_locations` from a union (with `undefined` possible values) into the type of a much simpler object. This won't affect things if you're just logging the result, but it'll let TS infer the value as a `string`, and not as `string | undefined`, and lets you avoid the ugly `as` assertion.

```
const gridData = [
  { "source_language": "en", "word": ...
] as const;
// ...
if (letterCoordinatesAsString in word_locations) {
    console.log(word_locations[letterCoordinatesAsString]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON is structured incorrectly. You are missing some curly brackets, try this...

```
const data = [
          { names: { "1,2": "Matthew" }},
          { names: { "2,3": "Marcus", "3,4": "Bill" }},
          { names: { "4,5": "Joana", "5,6": "Bob" }}
         ];
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j6Lcv9pa/

Comment: Just saw the missing curly brackets, thanks! However, I still get the same error ...

Comment: EDIT: I have adapted the code snippet in the question with the more complex code so that the error is reproducible